# Accesing iphone gps position from the macbook?

Tags: iphone, gps

I observed that an ipad (wifi) connected to a personal hotspot made by an iphone does get also the GPS position.

The question is how can I get this from a MacBook Pro?

I would like to use it with apps like Google Earth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an iPhone 4 to test this, but I assume Core Location will do.

[Here's a simple sample application with a map (and coordinates).](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/09/whereismymac-snow-leopard-corelocation.html)

[Lucubrator](http://www.quecheesoftware.com/Quechee_Software/Lucubrator.html) is also an option, and comes with some more information.